# correct way for loading dynamically all imgs from server using javascript and django

Tags: javascript, django

I need to dynamically load all images in a given directory from the server using javascript. I don't know in advance the number of files in the directory, neither their names. What is the correct way for doing this. Should I first send a request with ajax to get their names ? or is there another way. By the way, I'm using Django, and the images are in my static directory, though I don't think this information makes a difference.

Comment: You would need to know each `img` path to load all of them. There is not a way in client side javascript to load everything from `/images/**` into the DOM.

For what it's worth, this seems like an odd requirement. It might be worth revisiting why you want to do this in the first place.

Comment: @mcranston18, Thanks ! I actually have images classified by types, and when the user chooses a type, only these images are loaded. Same way, when he chooses another type, I have to load again corresponding imgs.

Comment: I see. My advice would be to keep a list of img path's which related to each type. When new images get added to your directory, you would manually update the list on the front end.

Comment: The thing is that I might have tens of images. Should I keep all their paths at the front end ?

Comment: That is what I would probably recommend. If you find that you really need a dynamic list, your Django API could return a list of paths to the front end, but I would store on the front end to keep it simple.